# Magento 2 REST API

Tags: php, node.js, rest, magento, magento2

I' m trying to create a node.js client for the Magento REST API.
I use the community edition running on my own centOS server.

The steps I follow to use the api:

- Create user with Administrator role in Magento admin panel
- Create new Integration
- Activate Integration (after this, I receive ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, AccessToken, SecretToken)

The problem is: when I try a get request to any endpoint I get:

```
{
Client is not authorized to access this resource: ResourceName
}
```

the request is:

```
request({
      url: this.url+endpoint,
      method: 'GET',
      headers:{
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+bearer,
        'User-Agent': '...',
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }, (error, response, body) => {
      callback(error,response,body)
    })

})
```

I correctly get the bearer ( I checked it ) token by this request:

```
request({
  url: this.url+'integration/admin/token',
  method: 'POST',
  json:{
    username: this.username,
    password: this.password
  }
}, (error, response, body) => {
    callback(body)
})
```

Navigating through the magento installation, I ran into the authorization request:

```
 public function isAllowed($resource, $privilege = null)
{
    return $this->_aclPolicy->isAllowed($this->_aclRoleLocator->getAclRoleId(), $resource, $privilege);
}
```

If I change into

```
return true
```

I get access to all the resources without authentication, but it' s not what I want

I checked the function

```
getAclRoleId()
```

and I found this DefaultRoleLocator.php

```
namespace Magento\Framework\Authorization\RoleLocator;

class DefaultRoleLocator implements 
\Magento\Framework\Authorization\RoleLocatorInterface
{
/**
 * Retrieve current role
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAclRoleId()
{
    return '';

}
}
```

I am not very good in PHP, and I' m a newbie on magento.
Even the oauth authentication fails.

I have to change this function ? 
I have to create another RoleLocator class ?

Any help would be really appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you added permissions to access the requested resource? [image: permissions]